# How to use IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged action message with caliburn?

Tags: wpf, caliburn

I've noticed sometimes I can not get certain ActionMessages to behave, for example:

```
<TextBox cal:Message.Attach="[Event IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged] = [Action Foo()]"/>
```

Will never call Foo, I'm forced to use code behind:

```
<TextBox IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged="Foo"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried writing Foo with out the () 

?

Comment: yeah, I've tried that... no luck

Comment: when 
<TextBox IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged="Foo"/> is generated in your code behind what is the method signture ?